# How to extract View article URL from the Outlook 2007 IPM.Post.Rss item?

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

Each Outlook 2007 RSS item (`MessageClass = "IPM.Post.Rss"`) has *View article...* URL. How to extract that? I think I can extract that from `objItem.HTMLBody` or from `objItem.Body` by parsing the text. But looks like it is incorrect approach - it will not work with non-Eng versions of Outlook. Also, it will not work properly if there is another link with the same text.

Is there any other way to get this URL?

Comment: I've found this article - http://www.ms-news.net/f1021/how-to-get-rss-specific-properties-from-a-postitem-with-message-class-ipm-post-rss-6702265.html, but not sure how to implement the same with VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/outlookdev/thread/4d5a89ec-74a4-45a4-bb5a-fc78da430847/) is the answer:

```
url = Item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062041-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8901001F")
```